# Which sukta of Yajurveda talks about vAjapeya

Tags: yajur-veda

Could you please tell me which mandala and sukta of yajurveda the following reference talking about:

*To me 1 of the most inspiring chants from the yajurveda is the chariot-race incantation used in the vAjapeya*

https://mobile.twitter.com/blog_supplement/status/1359396544416534529

*Update:*
Answers to tweet thread point to this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=1032&v=60XZ3k85IWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on the tweet thread:
https://mobile.twitter.com/sudarshanhs/status/1359444189109317632

Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60XZ3k85IWE&feature=emb_logo starts at 17:12

The english translation is titled "The Vajapeya" and i.7.8 in the link below
https://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/yajur_veda_1.asp#Pra7

Sanskrit text:
http://www.sanskritweb.net/yajurveda/ts-1-7.pdf
Verse [[1-7-8-1]] to [[1-7-8-4]]

Video clip
https://youtu.be/60XZ3k85IWE?start=1031&end=1168

```
देवस्याह सवितुः प्रसवे बृहस्पतिना वाजजिता वाजं जेषम्।
देवस्याह सवितुः प्रसवे बृहस्पतिना वाजजिता वर्षिष्ठं नाक रुहेयम् इन्द्राय
वाचं वदतेन्द्रं वाज जापयतेन्द्रो वाजमजयित्।
अश्वाजनि वाजिनि वाजेषु वाजिनीवत्यश्वान्त्स॒मत्सु वाजय।
अर्वाऽसि सप्तिरसि वाज्यसि
वाजिनो वाजं धावत मरुतां प्रसवे जयत वि योजना मिमीध्वमध्वनः स्कनीत॥
काष्ठा गच्छत
वाजेवाजे ऽवत वाजिनो नो धनेषु विप्रा अमृता ऋतज्ञा।
अस्य मध्वः पिबत मादयध्वं तृप्ता यात पृथिभिर्देव॒यानैः॥
ते नो अर्वन्तो हवन॒श्रुतो हवं विश्व शृण्वन्तु वाजिनः।
मितद्रवः सहस्रसा मेधाता सनिष्यवः।
महो ये रन्त समिथेषु जभ्रिरे शं नो भवन्तु वाजिनो हवैषु
देवताता मतद्रवः स्वर्काः।
जम्भयन्तोऽहिं वृकर रक्षासि सनैम्य॒स्मद्युयवन्न्॥
अमीवाः॥
एष स्य वाजी क्षिपणिं तुरण्यति ग्रीवायां बद्धो अपिकक्ष आसनि।
क्रतुं दधिक्रा अनु संतीत्वत् प॒थामङ्कारस्यन्वापनीफणत्॥
उत स्मास्य॒ द्रवतस्तुरण्यतः पूर्णं न वेरनु वाति प्रगर्धिनः।
श्येनस्यैव ध्रजतो अङ्कसं परि दधिकाव्णः सहोर्जा तरित्रतः॥
आ मा वाजस्य प्रसवो जगम्यादा द्यावापृथिवी विश्वशंभू।
आ मा गन्तां पितरा॥
मातरा चाऽऽ मा सोमौ अमृतत्वार्य गम्यात्॥
वाजिनो वाजजितो वाज सरिष्यन्तो वार्ज जेष्यन्तो बृहस्पतेर्भागमवं जिघ्रत॥
वाजिनो वाजजितो वाज ससृवासो वाजं जिगवासो बृहस्पतैर्भागे नि मृड्डम्
इयं वः सा सत्या संधाऽभूद्यामिन्द्रेण समधद्धम्
अजीजिपत वनस्पतय इन्द्रं वाजं वि मुच्यध्वम्॥
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could copy the relevant part here in the answer and put it in block quotes.

Comment: Difficult to copy from PDF

Comment: Try [OCR](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/616/use-ocr-to-post-answers-from-pdfs-which-are-not-text-searchable) to copy text from PDF to here. I really want to upvote the answer for that YouTube link you provided too but since it’s link only it’s little difficult. And please do quote at least part of the English version alongside.

Comment: Will attempt today

Comment: @Archit added the verse above, used OCR

Comment: Great. You got your vote :)